# Microsoft Windows ISO checksums

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-8, windows-vista, checksum

Is there an official source for Windows ISO (XP+) checksums, online?

Wanting to download some older Windows versions, for support purposes, but they don't appear to be available on Microsoft's website, so I am having to find 3rd party copies.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thanks. I don't have a MSDN subscription, and had a decent look for this online before posting. Have (a) link(S) for any/all of these on Technet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An MSDN subscription is not needed to browse the contents on the [Subscriber Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/) page.

Once there, you can browse to any product and click on the `Details` link to see the SHA1 hash for the product

for ex.:
[Windows XP Service Pack 3 (x86) - CD (English)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/#FileId=15565)

> Windows XP Service Pack 3 (x86) - CD (English)
>   SHA1: 8fa76ccea145d050fc6a506ffbdedfe53282e5b4

Comment: Thanks for the link Tulhan. Went back to google with "[Windows XP SHA1](https://www.google.com/webhp?channel=fflb#q=Windows+XP+SHA1+site%3Amicrosoft.com)" search, and it still didn't come up in the first few pages. Finding info on Microsoft websites (by proxy, through search engines like Google) seems to be a constant challenge for me. Black box it is.

Comment: @user66001 I have absolutely no issues finding the hashes for any product. Added screenshots to the post if it is of any help.

Comment: Sorry, I should have probably worded my last comment better. Your answer is correct, hence marked as such. Was just commenting that this is the reason for the question, given *my* difficulty (in general) with finding official info on MS's websites. It was also partly to address Ramhound's comment that seemed to suggest it was an easy answer (Now deleted, it seems). P.S I actually liked the previous version of your answer :)

Comment: @user66001 Ah! okay. Glad to be of help. Rolled back to previous version. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any tricks to finding info on MS's website (presuming you use search engines, and not just go directly to MS's website, and use their search engine)?

Comment: I use Google's [site operator](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35256?hl=en). For your question, i used the query `windows xp sha1 site:microsoft.com`, which led me to an MSDN help article that gave me the answer.

Comment: Very interesting. Check out the link in my first comment. It's the same :s

Comment: Do you know how to get checksums for older versions, namely Windows 2000?

Comment: The above answer to this question appears to now not work. The Subscriber Downloads link in that answer requires a Microsoft Account to login. Once logged in, a message appears saying:
> Good news! Your subscription(s) has been migrated to a new portal.
> Visit my.visualstudio.com/downloads to access your downloads using the same email address Following that link does not display the official checksums for the ISO images as the OP requested. Another possible solution for OP is to calculate the checksum from the downloaded ISO file, Google the calculated checksum, and hope that it has been post

Comment: What a travesty that Microsoft has removed these checksums.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1126483/27671)...

```
Service Pack 2 and Service Pack 3 are available from Microsoft here: http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/

You must use Internet Explorer 6 or later.

Search for "XP Service Pack" (without quotes)
```

Direct link to above search:

http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=XP%20Service%20Pack

And the Win XP service pack 3 sha1 there is c81472f7eeea2eca421e116cd4c03e2300ebfde4 - also tested with the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is third-party service to acquire MS Windows ISO checksums:

- https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php