# What is a safe download link for Windows XP Service Pack 3?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, download, service-pack

Is this still available from MS? If not can someone suggest a reliable 3rd party site that does not bundle adware/malware into the download?

Comment: I would be happy to use another version of Windows if someone would give me valid product key. Unfortunately Windows XP is the only licensed version of Windows I own. I've installed this in a VM and plan to only use the RDP client to connect to my work network. No way I would use XP as a workstation of daily driver.

Comment: You know Linux has _two_ RDP clients on its own?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: @grawity: There are more than 2 RDP clients that run natively on Linux. Believe me, I've tried to find a Linux solution to avoid the overhead of running a VM. I can't find a Linux client that provides RD Gateway support which is a requirement for me.

Comment: @concordia: FreeRDP 1.2 definitely does.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Service Pack 2 and Service Pack 3 are available from Microsoft here:  http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/

You must use Internet Explorer 6 or later.

Search for "XP Service Pack" (without quotes)

Answer (score 10):

Note that SP3 *itself* is quite old by now; even with it installed, you'll still need to check Windows Update (if it still works) for a few more years' worth of patches.

Archived SP3 download links from the official website are:

- Digitally signed EXE installer (Authenticode):
  [WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20130206044040/http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/3/0/d30e32d8-418a-469d-b600-f32ce3edf42d/WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe)
  SHA1: c81472f7eeea2eca421e116cd4c03e2300ebfde4
- ISO image:
  [xpsp3_5512.080413-2113_usa_x86fre_spcd.iso](http://web.archive.org/web/20150213193534/http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/e/9/ee9d0116-c9fe-4fc2-b59c-406cbfb6d515/xpsp3_5512.080413-2113_usa_x86fre_spcd.iso)
  *aka* en_windows_xp_service_pack_3_x86_cd_x14-60489.iso
  SHA1: 8fa76ccea145d050fc6a506ffbdedfe53282e5b4

Comment: Had to get an old computer onto SP3 after installing SP1 from a disk. The first link worked great!

Comment: Got SP1 somewhere? It's needed before SP3...

Comment: Search for `en_winxp_sp1.iso`, SHA1 `15d98191e64447be044a3af20a2fa3730f125c89`.

Answer (score 1):

MS seem to have removed the XP down-loads from their site, so you are stuck with finding third-party down-loads. If you find more than one with the same MD5 check-sum, and you have a good virus scanner which finds no problems, you will have a degree of assurance that the down-load is safe.

However, MS continue to support XP covertly in the guise of WePOS, and [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3740) seems to work for the present. You may need to install the registry patch detailed [here](http://xdot.tk/) before you can install it.

Whatever you do, so you *must* back up everything profusely before attempting to install anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to use the link xav-stargate provided to get the service pack. The xdot.tk site looks like a wealth of information. It may provide useful if I need to patch this install of XP further.

Comment: @concordia - OK. I used Ubuntu yesterday, as I wasn't able to check from the XP system, but now I've done so I see that xap-stargate's link works fine.