# Is there a way to download or verify a Windows installation ISO officially?

Tags: windows

So I already knew there's tons of places you can get a Windows install ISO, and some website even post a checksum for verifying, but what if I don't trust any third party and want it directly from Microsoft, or at least a Microsoft certified website? Can I download the ISO file or view the checksum from a trusted place?

Comment: Like this? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download Windows 7/8.1/10 images [directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/)

As for checksum, see [Microsoft Windows ISO checksums](https://superuser.com/a/662208/657763).

Answer (score 2):

I also found an answer myself:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/